# is a**n O(1) or is it O(n) hence called recursively in python compiler?

Tags: python, time-complexity, pow, exponent

Is a**n similar to pow(a,n) in time complexity hence called recursively or is it linear time as it is a mathematical expression that might be computed directly ?

They provide similar time() o/p in smaller inputs but varying in larger ones but that may not indicate a complexity difference so i'm not sure